# Most negative number (in octal and hex) of a 16-bit one's complement system?

Tags: computer-science, computer-arithmetic

In a 16-bit one's complement system, how do you represent the most negative number in octal and hex?

One's complement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones'_complement

The most negative 16-bit number in the one's complement system is -32767. In hex, this number is: 8001. However, converting the one's complement binary representation of -32767 (1000 0000 0000 0000) to hex gives 8000. What gives?

NOTE: Since computers cannot store negative signs, I am omitting them. Hence, F7A is -134 in base 10 and not 3962.

Comment: In hex, that number is $-7FFF$, not $+77777$.

Comment: Jik, my mistake, I wrote the wrong number. I am using this conversion tool in conjunction with my own calculations:

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-hex.htm

So (-32767) in base 10 is (8001) in base 16.

Comment: (Also, since computers do not have negative signs, I omitted them.)

Comment: "Also, since computers do not have negative signs, I omitted them." This is confusing. You are asking about one way to represent negative integers as binary strings ("one's complement"), and in your question you use some other way of representing negative integers as positive integers. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The number $32768$ has a binary representation $1000\ 0000\ 0000\ 0000$ and a hex representation $8000$.

The point of one's complement is that because the string $1000\ 0000\ 0000\ 0000$ has a $1$ at its first coordinate, it does not mean the positive integer but the negative integer whose binary representation is $-111\ 1111\ 1111\ 1111$. That number is $-32767$, or $-7FFF$ in hex.

Comment: I am getting confused. Let's start here: what is the one's complement binary represenation of -32767 (i.e., the most negative 16-bit number in one's complement)?

Comment: @Brian:  I gave that in hex.  In binary it is 1000 0000 0000 0000, which you get by inverting each bit in $+32767_{10}= $0111 1111 1111 1111$_2$

Comment: Ah, I see you answered my question. I will continue with my logic above...

Answer (score 0):

In ones complement notation, you are correct that the most negative number that fits in $16$ bits is $-32767_{10}$  If you convert this to signed octal you get $-077777_8$ or in hex it is $-7FFF_{16}$.  If you convert it to ones complement, you get $100000_8$ or $ 8000_{16}$  In a sixteen bit octal word, the lower five digits (octits?) represent three bits each, while the leading one is a single bit to make sixteen.  What do you think is wrong about $8000_{16}$?  You said it was octal, but it is hex, and a fine hex number at that.

Comment: According to my calculations, -32767 in base 10 is 8001 in base 16. You can check with this conversion tool:

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm

Also, since computers cannot store negative signs, I am omitting the symbol.

Comment: Now, my confusion is why the conversion from -32767 to hex is not the same as the conversion from the one's complement binary representation of -32767 (1000 0000 0000 0000) to hex.

Comment: The ones' complement value of $-32767_{10}$ is $8000_{16}$.  For ones' complement you just reverse all the bits.  The twos' complement value of $-32767_{10}$ is $8001_{16}$.  In ones' complement there are two zeros, $0000_{16}$ and $FFFF_{16}$.  Your calculator is doing twos' complement, which is what normal computers use, but you specified ones' complement in your question.

Comment: I appreciate the back and forth - I hope you don't mind if I continue to ask questions so that I get this down. I have a few questions for you, and maybe you will see where I'm coming from, or I will see the error of my ways. Here is one: what is the binary representation of the base 10 number -32767 in the one's complement system? Is it not 1000 0000 0000 0000?

Comment: It is.  Ones' complement seems a natural way to represent negative numbers, but it is a pain to calculate with.  Twos' complement is more difficult to explain (why the added $1$?), but your arithmetic can ignore the sign on numbers and just proceed.  Computers use it for that reason.  You seem to understand how to do ones' complement.  There are 65536 16 bit strings.  In ones' complement, they represent the range of -32767 through +32767 with two zeros.  If you count them they are all accounted for.

Comment: (I see that you answered my question below, but I will continue here). So the hex representation of this number is 8000. Now, here is where things get confusing for me. In the two's complement system, the most negative 16-bit number is -32678, and it's hex representation is also 8000. But this should not be since -32768 < -32767.

Comment: It's  kind of convoluted, but here is my best shot at summarizing why I am in the dark: the most negative 16-bit number in the one's complement system is -32767. In the two's complement system, the number is -32768. Now, when you convert these numbers to their binary equivalent, and then convert to hex, you get the same number in hex: 8000. What I don't understand is how this can be.

Comment: In twos' complement, you shift all the negatives down one compared to ones' complement.  Why should the ranges match? They are two different systems.  I could define a new representation by saying $0000_{16}$ represents $-1024_{10}$ and $FFFF_16$ represents $65536-1024=64512_{10}$  This might be handy if I have a case where there aren't large negative numbers, but the positives will overflow a standard $16$ bit int.  The number of values has to match, but not the range.